# Trying to call post title, excerpt, and permalink from id for shorcode

Tags: php, wordpress

I was able to get the title and excerpt to display correctly, but I can't figure out which permalink call to use.

```
function display_excerpt_shortcode( $atts ) {
  extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    'excerptid' => ''
  ), $atts));
  if ($excerptid) {
    $args=array(
    'p' => $excerptid,
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish'
  );
    $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
    if ($my_query) {
        $title = apply_filters( 'the_title', $my_query->posts[0]->post_title );
        $excerpt = apply_filters( 'the_excerpt', $my_query->posts[0]->post_excerpt );
        $link = apply_filters( 'the_permalink', $my_query->posts[0]->post_permalink );

        return '<h3>' . $title . '</h3> <p>' . $excerpt . '</p> <a class="button small primary" href="' . $link . '" title="' . $title . '" >Read More </a>';
    }
  }
  return;
}
add_shortcode('display_excerpt', 'display_excerpt_shortcode');
```

I've tried all kinds of combinations. the_permalink, get_permalink, post_permalink... I just can't figure out if it's the wrong combination or if I'm just completely off the mark. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

`$link = get_permalink( $my_query->posts[0]->post_ID )`

I think your problem is that the query object has no 'permalink' property.
Following the guide in the [codex's class reference page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query), you'll find the pattern of setting a new post object during each iteration of the loop with `$the_query->the_post();`:

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        //Now reference WP post functions:
        the_title();
        the_permalink();
    }
}
```

Sorry it's a totally different design, but this has never failed me.

Comment: This works for pulling all of the values, but unfortunately it echos instead of returning the values and won't display the way I want it to from the shortcode.

Comment: Actually, you were totally right. Your first bit of code did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: Awesome. For the Second example you would use the 'get_the' family of functions like `$link = get_the_permalink();`